# Eigenvalue problem with periodic boundary conditions: Are these solutions consistent?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, periodic-functions

I am reading about the eigenvalue problem

$$-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}u = \lambda u$$

with periodic boundary conditions.

[This article](https://www.iist.ac.in/sites/default/files/people/IN08026/Eigenvalue.pdf) (equation 12b) implies the eigenfunctions have the forms

$$u(x) = 1\\ u(x) = A\cos(n\pi x/L)\\u(x) = A\sin(n\pi x/L)$$

However, I thought the correct form was

$$u(x) = Ae^{i n\pi x/L}$$

Are these two forms related or somehow equivalent?

Comment: Note by Euler we know that $e^{in\pi x/L}= \cos(n\pi x/L)+i\sin(n\pi x/L)$.

Comment: Would I be right in thinking we can build the Exp[] solution from a linear combination of the sin and cos solutions since (if I understand correctly), they have the same eigenvalue?

Comment: That is along the same lines that I am thinking. I apologize that I am not 100% sure on this... I am hoping someone else may be able to help out...

Comment: You want to solve the ODE $$u'' = -\lambda u, \quad \lambda > 0 \quad (*)$$ This is linear, so by making the ansatz $u = e^{\gamma x}$ we find that $\gamma = \pm i \sqrt{\lambda} \implies u_{1,2} = e^{i \sqrt{\lambda} x}, e^{-i \sqrt{\lambda} x}$. By linearity, we know that the sum of two solutions is also a solution, hence the most general solution to $(*)$ is $$u = a_{1} e^{i \sqrt{\lambda} x} + a_{2} e^{-i \sqrt{\lambda} x}$$ Now use Eulers identity so get the solution in terms of sines and cosines. Finally, apply the boundary conditions to find the form of $\lambda$.